# Save raster layers in a python script

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

Is there a way to loop through every selected layer in qgis and save it as a .tif file with the same layer name using a python script?

This is the code I am using, but it does nothing at all. It runs but does nothing.

Can someone help me?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import os
import sys


layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    output='Desktop'%layer.name%'.tif'
shareeditundeleteflag
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess thoses layers are all rasters to begin with. You could find a way by importing qgis core and processing inside a Python shell. By doing this you can extract the selected items from qgis. For the processing afterwards you could use the gdal merge tool as if you were running an algorythm or calling a function. I must have a python code where i did something like this somewhere i think.

EDIT: Ok so the Python importing and initialization of the whole code should be something like this:

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
qgis.path.insert(0, 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python')
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

You'll need the sys and OS modules for what you want to do, almost 100%. If you want to import the processing tools from qgis it'll be something like this:

```
# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
```

That'll import the whole toolbox, for running tools just use the `general.runalg('your tool name', 'data in', 'data ou')` prompt, you'll need to look for the tool's name and options beforhand inside the python console built in qgis.

Comment: That would convert the layer to a raster layer, but how would save that converted layer as a tif file?

Comment: A bit late to add to it but you can force him to make a tif file by simply setting the output file as one when you tell him where to save it (just add the extension at the end after your file's name, worked for me when i had to do this on 20 files or more at a time)

Comment: But how would I save this in python code, is there a command to do this?

Comment: I dont quite remember what tool i used but you can extract layers opened by qgis into a python script fairly easily. I think i was using something like `Layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`. If it works out, it'll extract your active layers into a new variable called layer, that's your input. Afterwards, just set the output as follow `ouput = 'your_file_path.tif'` and it should do the trick;

Comment: You could also completly bypass qgis by getting everything in the same folder if you need to but that's another story.

Comment: I made some adjustments to the code I am trying to use, and I will post it in the question as an edit.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work, please see the edited question, there is the code.

Comment: Is `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python` the place where your qgis python directory is located? If not change it and make it match the real path.because you HAVE to set the thing if you are working outside of qgis python console or he'll never be able to use and initiate qgis outside of it's usual workspace. Afterwards opening your processing toolbox is actually quite simple, just do the same and don't forget to set the path to your processing folder. If you are working with said console a simple `import processing` will work to set up the workspace and initialize the whole thing.

Comment: That and the output is false in what i saw of your code